# Spatial Probability Density Function Contouring

Tags: r

[image: density]
So i'm trying to create a contour plot based on specific point patterns. I want to make it so when the density of the points goes below a certain threshold it stops that contour and starts another. So I want to incorporate a SPDF in to my project here. This is a snipit of what the code would look like with the points scattered within a boundary. The points also wouldn't necessarily be random, but possibly uniform.

```
   library(spatstat)
   rect <- owin(c(0, 10), c(1, 4))
   rect <- rpoint(100, win = rect)
```

Comment: Need data. Do a search on simulating point processes. Use `set.seed` to allow reproducibility. Also need a better verbal description. Saying you want to "stop a contour" is not particularly clear. Say what you expect to see.

Comment: @42-, the picture I added above is essentially what I want to do. I want to, within a boundary, apply a function to cluster points based on a certain cutoff. The trouble I am running in to is the syntax of code that allows the code to run across all of the points

Comment: You are illustrating desity estimation for  univariate process but you code creates a 2D process.

Comment: @42-, based on the code I have I want to be able to contour the points using spatial density. I want to be able to set the contour threshold though, which is the (C -----) above. I have a large dataset of latitude and longitude points and I want to be able to write a spdf to contour it based on my own specified density levels if that makes more sense.